# It is possible to break Maven builds when SonarQube detects new violations, without using the Build Breaker plugin?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I want to be able to completely stop a Maven build process in case SonarQube detects new rule violations during incremental analyses in the developer's machines. I want to do this in order to force the developers to verify their code quality prior to checking their changes in to the SCM (Apache Subversion, in our case).

The Build Breaker plugin is not a possibility since it doesn't break the build. It lets the build finish successfully, and only reports a status of BUILD FAILURE. Furthermore, Build Breaker is not supported anymore for SonarQube 5.1+ for preview/incremental modes.

Comment: Side note: I would be careful about breaking the build there. You don't want your developers to think of your build setup as something that "punishes" them. If you spoke to them; and they all agree that things should work like this; then it is fine to do so. But if you did not ask for their consent: be prepared for all kinds of reactions. And even if nobody complains loudly - maybe people start to "work" around your ideas to "force" them to do something. You know - smart people will always find ways to "trick" you; and you don't want to get into such a "race"!

Comment: I agree that you should use the carrot rather than the stick. Sometimes the march of progress requires that technical debt be added. You don't want to make your project un-buildable if someone _must_ add an issue.

Answer (score 0):

i created a plugin for this behavior (and by extend to link sonar to my maven projects): https://github.com/VandeperreMaarten/sonar-maven-plugin .

The only thing you need to do is

add following plugin to your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.viae-it.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>LATEST</version>
</plugin>
```

call the plugin to validate the

```
mvn com.viae-it.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:validate-qualitygate
```